# How to I bake the displacement texture on an image?

Tags: uv, texture-baking, displacement

Ultimately, I'm trying to bake the displacement map to actually deform the mesh of an object.
In the end, I should end up with a baked displacement texture, and use it in a "displace" modifier to deform the mesh

I'm following this tutorial that shows how to do that
https://youtu.be/H51zh25KGGY?si=oDOyCmxZtLDdnZ8F

My only issue is the part where I need to bake the displacement texture on an image texture. I need to un-wrap the UV so it fits within the bounds of the UV map. But by doing that, it makes my UV scaled up like crazy, which is definitely not what I want.

Exemple:
[image]

What the texture **should** look like. (on the right)
[image]

Nodes:
[image]

Does anyone know how I can work around this issue?

Here is my blend file, for anyone interested
https://we.tl/t-OMTSDZ3PRF

Comment: So your question is not about baking, more about the UV that is too big? What you could do is playing with the scale of the Mapping node, to do that, plug an Input Value into the Scale input of the Mapping and play with the value? If this is not your problem, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @moonboots

Changing the scale was the solution, thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to bake your displacement?  You already have an image with the displacement you want.  You're not changing your mapping or anything.  You can use the existing displacement texture in a displacement modifier.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the UV islands size, you could play with the *Scale* values of the *Mapping* node. To make it simpler, plug an *(Input) Value* node into the *Scale* input of the *Mapping* node and play with the value:

[image]